# ASP.NET Core MVC- localhost is currently unable to handle this request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a simple application.
Index.cshtml page shows a login page, this page has User Model binded to it. Whenever the login form is submitted from Index.cshtml page, controller httppost action method Login is called which simply looks for correct username and password and if the user is present it simply redirects the user to Login.cshtml view with a list of users as shown below:

**Index C# Code:**

```
 public IActionResult Index()  //simply return the login page view
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model NewChatApp.Models.User    

<div class="wrapper fadeInDown">
<div id="formContent" class="mt-5">
    <form method="post" class="mt-5" asp-action="Login">
        <input hidden="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
        <input hidden="hidden" asp-for="Name" />
        <input type="text" class="fadeIn second" placeholder="login" asp-for="Username">
        <input type="text" class="fadeIn third" placeholder="password" asp-for="Password">
        <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth mt-3" value="Log In">
    </form>

</div>
```

**Login C# Code:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login(User user)
    {
        UserProvider userProvider = new UserProvider();
        User user1 = userProvider.CreateUsersList().Where(x => x.Username == user.Username && x.Password == user.Password).FirstOrDefault();
        TempData["CurrentUser"] = user1;
        if (user1 == null)
        {
            ViewData.Clear();
            return View("Index");
        }
        List<User> users = userProvider.CreateUsersList().Where(x => x.Id != user1.Id).ToList();
        return View(users);
    }
```

**Login.cshtml Code**

```
@model IEnumerable<NewChatApp.Models.User>

@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="col-md-3">
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                FRIENDS
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (User item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-link">@item.Name</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When i debug the code. I see that i successfully get the user model in login method and login method then return list of three user to login view. In the login view in foreach loop when i iterate through the user records, on first iteration of foreach loop it shows error in browser that **localhost is currently unable to handle this request**
I have enabled developer exception page as well in startup class but wont get the detailed error.

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

Comment: You dont see any exceptions in the Output window?

Comment: ystem.InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Infrastructure.DefaultTempDataSerializer' cannot serialize an object of type 'NewChatApp.Models.User'.
I see this in output window

Comment: Issue was with the TempData in the Login method. Not sure why error was occurring when i store User object in TempData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the output window as instructed by [Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1519744/frank-nielsen) in the comment, i was able to figure out that the issue was with storing of User object in the TempData. I removed that line and all started working.
Updated Login C# Code:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Login(User user)
{
    UserProvider userProvider = new UserProvider();
    User user1 = userProvider.CreateUsersList().Where(x => x.Username == user.Username && x.Password == user.Password).FirstOrDefault();
    
    if (user1 == null)
    {
        ViewData.Clear();
        return View("Index");
    }
    List<User> users = userProvider.CreateUsersList().Where(x => x.Id != user1.Id).ToList();
    return View(users);
}
```